# Pulling data into Excel from multiple pages

Tags: excel, vba

I’m currently trying to pull data from an internal website. However, a few challenges stand in my way. For clarity, I’ve attached a screenshot of the interface I’m working with. I’ve removed all of the text and added my own references for confidentiality purposes. 
The data I need to pull is in Tab1 > TabD. I then apply a filter to it (not sure if that’s relevant here). In this example, there are 16 pages and it is these 16 pages of data (headers 1 to 5) that I need to pull into an excel sheet.

There’s no API for this and the page number doesn’t change in the URL so it can’t be used (to my knowledge).

With all these conditions, is this even feasible with VBA?

Thank you all for your time.

[image: interfacescreenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I WOULD just comment on this. But I don't have enough reputation to do so. Come on StackOverflow, I want to help people! I'll leave an answer instead, though I may need more information.

I am assuming this is done in Internet Explorer. In which case if you press Ctrl+U you can bring up the source for a page. Bring up the source to the page shown in your screenshot. You'll need to look for a javascript button that changes the page, which is the tricky part. The syntax for such a button in javascript looks like this:

```
<button onclick="functionToRun()">Button Text</button>
```

The button in the example above runs the function "functionToRun." Once you find the function that changes the page, insert it into the VBA line below, once you have IE properly initialized in your script:

```
Call IE.document.parentWindow.execScript("functionToRun()", "JavaScript")
```

The line above runs the JavaScript function in IE, effectively changing the page.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks very much for your reply. Actually, this is in FF. I can see the page source there as well but cannot seem to find anything called "functionToRun" or "button onclick". Does it have another name in FF? Thanks, Max.

Comment: Firefox won't affect the page source, but it is not something I know how to automate with VBA, there might be a guide somewhere explaining how to click a button with FF controlled with VBA. But I think it'll probably be easier to use IE just for automation purposes.

The button may not be coded with JavaScript, perhaps PHP, which wouldn't be a problem. See if you can fins a button in the source, and post a screenshot so it can be identified.

Comment: I swtiched to IE if that makes things easier to link with VBA. I've found the following code in the source:

'<div class="a-popover-header">
            <h4>edit</h4>    
            <button data-action="z-popover-close a-popover-close"
               class="a-declarative a-button-close" data-close-triggers="{"escKeys":true,"outsideClicks":true}">
               <i class="a-icon a-icon-close"></i>
            </button>
         </div>'